# Add and remove Icon to the button in sencha touch dynamically

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

> I want to add close icon to the button after the text. For this I am
>   trying to insert sibling in the element. I achieved this in ExtJs by
>   doing :

```
            button.btnWrap.insertSibling({
                tag: 'a',
                cls: me.closeIconCls,
                title: me.closeText
            }, 'after');
```

> Can same be done in touch.I tried but its not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to the documentation, this should work. Have you tried a simple example in a fiddle?

Comment: I achieved that using 'setIconCls'. Thnks